# BlockingQueue on main Service thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service, blockingqueue

My android app has a long running background service, which I also understand runs in the application's main thread and for that reason, any time consuming or blocking task should be moved to a separate thread.

Now, here is the situation, I don't understand/confused about:

When I bind to the service from an activity, i receive an reference to the service which allows me to invoke service methods from my activity. One of the methods allows me to pass a String object from the activity to the service, which is then added to a `BlockingQueue`. A separate worker thread which is started in the Service's onCreate method, checks the queue for available data and then performs the required task.

What I want to understand is, if at some point, the queue becomes full and an attempt to the queue blocks, will it affect the main thread the service is running on?

Comment: Why do you use a `BlockingQueue` ? Do you have any requirements for the producer ? I mean, does the situation of the queue being full and the producer bean blocked is what you want, or is a a side effect that isn't wanted ?

Comment: It is important the object be added to the queue. Therefore, if queue is full, it should block till there is available space for the object to be added.

Comment: So you've git some producer-consume model. Why does the producer run on the main thread in the first place ?

Comment: The actual data comes from a field in a Activity and it is passed to the queue in the service by invoking a method on the service instance and then passing the data object as an argument. The method then adds the object to a queue where the consuming thread fetches it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In this situation, if the queue becomes full, the calling thread will block (in your situation, the main thread). So this is a bad design.

The produced data coming from a field of an `Activity` doesn't force you to use it on the main thread. I suggest you use some `Handler` for your producer running on its own thread which will allow you to make the processing (and eventually waiting on the queue) outside of the main thread.

This is also good for communicating with your `Service` since you can use `Handlers` to communicate with a `Service` (see [Android Services' guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService)).

Finally, if applying the produced data can be passed directly to an `Handler` using either 
`Handler.post(Runnable)` or `Handler.send(Message)`

Comment: Thanks so much for the expert advice. Just what I needed. I knew something was definitely wrong with the way I implemented it. Thank you.